# keyboard shortcut to move window between monitors

Tags: 16.04

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> will move/dock window inside current monitor.

I'm using 3 monitors.

how do I move window between monitors?

Answer (score 1):

Following shortcut works for me (16.04):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd>

Comment: Thanks but not working, using default settings

Comment: doesn't work. Don't find anything related on keyboard shortcuts.